# layout setting in form designing using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I want to design a JFrame form using NetBeans . Is there any layout so that the controls should arrange according to the screen pixels according to the screen size. I am using absolute layout.

But in this, the positions of the controls is being disturbed in the form, so which layout should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check this out for more details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

Read on those layouts & apply the one that suits you best.